# Filtering an array of JSON objects with strange characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects given in the format below as an input, with odd double backslashes that stop me from parsing each input into JSON. I only want to save some document types, so I'm filtering out these records using Array.prototype.filter().  The problem I'm facing is parsing each record with those backslashes.  One is escaping the other and it's keeping one backslash. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const records = [
  {
    messageId: '1',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm1"\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
  {
    messageId: '2',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm3\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
  {
    messageId: '3',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm8\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
];

let output = [];
let message = [];
try {
    output = event.Records.filter((resource) => {
    console.log('resource:', resource);
    const body = resource.body ? JSON.stringify(resource.body) : '';
    message = body.Message ? JSON.stringify(resource.body.Message) : '';
    console.log('message:', message);
    const documentType = message.detail?.documentType?.toLowerCase() || '';
    console.log('decoumentType:', documentType);
    const acceptedDocTypes = ['pm1', 'pm2', 'pm3', 'pm4', 'pm5'];
    return acceptedDocTypes.includes(documentType);
});
```

---

UPDATED SNIPPET:

```
  try {
output = event.Records.filter((resource) => {
  let body = '';
  if (resource.body) {
    resource.body.replace(/(\\+")/gmi, '"');
    resource.body.replace(/\s*"\s*\{/gmi, '{').replace(/\s*\}\s*"/gmi, '}');
    body = JSON.parse(resource.body);
  }
  message = body.Message ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body.Message)) : '';
  console.log(message);
  const { documentType } = body.message.detail;
  console.log('decoumentType:', documentType);
  const acceptedDocTypes = ['pm1', 'pm2', 'pm3', 'pm4', 'pm5'];
  return acceptedDocTypes.includes(documentType);
});
```

Comment: Everywhere you're using `JSON.stringify()` should be `JSON.parse()`

Comment: The fact that `\\"pm1"\\"` has an unescaped quote is a mistake, isn't it? Because the other `pm` have only escaped quotes

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Edits that invalidate existing answers are likewise not allowed. Content posted on Stack Overflow is licensed under the CC By-SA license, meaning you grant the site the license to retain and modify that content in perpetuity.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `JSON.parse()` to parse JSON, since `body` and `Message` are JSON strings.

```js
const records = [{
    messageId: '1',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm1"\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
  {
    messageId: '2',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm3\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
  {
    messageId: '3',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm8\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
];

let output = [];
let message = [];
output = records.filter((resource) => {
  console.log('resource:', resource);
  const body = resource.body ? JSON.parse(resource.body) : {};
  message = body.message ? JSON.parse(body.Message) : {};
  console.log('message:', message);
  const documentType = message?.detail?.documentType?.toLowerCase() || '';
  console.log('decoumentType:', documentType);
  const acceptedDocTypes = ['pm1', 'pm2', 'pm3', 'pm4', 'pm5'];
  return acceptedDocTypes.includes(documentType);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If your backslashes are consistent, you can try removing them using a regex:

```js
const records = [
  {
    messageId: '2',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm3\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
  {
    messageId: '3',
    body: '{"Message" : "{\\"detail\\": {\\"documentType\\": \\"pm8\\", \\"documentDate\\": \\"2018-08-27 04:00:00\\"}}"}',
  },
]

records.forEach(record => record.body = record.body.replace(/(\\+")/gmi, '"'))

records.forEach(record => record.body = record.body.replace(/\s*"\s*\{/gmi, '{').replace(/\s*\}\s*"/gmi, '}'))

records.forEach(record => record.body = JSON.parse(record.body))

console.log(records)
```

In this way, you first clean the input, then you can apply `JSON.parse`. This doesn't work with your first example since there's an extra unescaped quote, but I suppose it was a typo in your writing.

Comment: I started refactoring and have ended up with this snippet below, but I'm getting an error saying Cannot read property 'detail' of undefined.  Code is too long to post in this comment so I'll update the question.